# PHP - How to get a file name from url string

Tags: php

This is a follow up on this question [Use PHP to Get File Path/Extension from URL string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16582359/use-php-to-get-file-path-extension-from-url-string)

Given a string which is a URL: [http://i.imgur.com/test.png&stuff](https://i.imgur.com/test.png&stuff)

How do I get the name of a file: `test.png` without query parameters?

If I try suggested solution: `parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH)` I get `/test.png&stuff`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it's not using a normal URL string, since it doesn't have the ? to separate out the query string.  You may want to try using a few different functions together:

```
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$path = explode('&',$path);
$filename = $path[0]; // and here is your test.png
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH) I get /test.png&stuff
> ```

That's because you're giving it a URL which contains no query string. You meant `/text.php?stuff`; the *query string* is defined by an `?`, not a `&`; `&` is used to append additional variables.

To extract the query string, you want `PHP_URL_QUERY`, not `PHP_URL_PATH`.

```
$x = "http://i.imgur.com/test.png?stuff";

parse_url($x, PHP_URL_QUERY); # "stuff"
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's user input. So user might input an invalid URL like  http://i.imgur.com/YsSs2FK.png&stuff that pulls up in a browser...

Comment: Then tell them their input is invalid. If they're feeding you bad input, you should *tell* them it's bad input, not try to guess at what they meant to type. In the case of your imgur link, the `&stuff` isn't *doing* anything, so you probably don't need to extract anything.

Answer (score 0):

based on @[Mark Rushakoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126042/mark-rushakoff)'s answer the best solution:

```
<?php
$path = "http://i.imgur.com/test.png?asd=qwe&stuff#hash";
$vars =strrchr($path, "?"); // ?asd=qwe&stuff#hash
var_dump(preg_replace('/'. preg_quote($vars, '/') . '$/', '', basename($path))); // test.png
?>
```

1. [Regular Expression to collect everything after the last /](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150559/regular-expression-to-collect-everything-after-the-last)
2. [How to get file name from full path with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418193/how-to-get-file-name-from-full-path-with-php)